# Sitecore PDF Document Content Indexing with Lucene

Tags: content-search, indexing

I assume with the latest releases of Sitecore (8.2), PDF and other document indexing comes by default.

Can someone please point me to a document related to any setting, to enable these media document indexing feature with sitecore ?

OR is there any custom code modifications involve with PDF media document content indexing with sitecore lucene ?

Thank you

Comment: Doens't work OOTB, you have to install IFilter. You don't have to modify your code. please have a look on the above link

Comment: This is not out of the box functionality. There are some solutions which add PDF-Indexing to the lucene functionalities. With Coveo, this is possible out of the box

Comment: @SitecoreClimber As I can see in that thread you pointed, we just needs to install IFilter in our environment. Other configurations seems there by default when check in the configs.

Comment: Exactly. The answer that I posted I got it from Sitecore support